# how to know if the given multiway tree is the sub structure of another multiway tree

Tags: multiway-tree

Given a big multiway tree `A` and a small multiway tree `B`, how can we know if `B` is a sub-structue of `A`？

Answer (score 0):

Finally, I found a python package `networkx` which can solve my problem

```py
gm = isomorphism.DiGraphMatcher(graph,subgraph, node_match)
gm.subgraph_is_isomorphic()
```